# Alternating background color of product blocks on Shopify?

Tags: html, css, shopify

I'm wondering if there is a way to alternate the background colors of product blocks in Shopify via editing shop code. Here's an example of what that would look like:

[Mockup of alternating blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y1aB.png)

How it is set up right now is this same grid but just with a black background for everything, with white lines separating the blocks. Is there a way to tell the background color to be white with every other product, or something similar?

Answer (score 3):

See `:nth-child` pseudo class :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

For example `tr:nth-child(even)` or `tr:nth-child(2n)`
Represents the even rows of an HTML table: 2, 4, 6, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use the `:nth-child` pseudo-class. This can be
done in a number of ways. If I were you, I'd go with:

[An example of the :nth-child(eve) selector in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIIh9.png)

```
.product:nth-child(even) {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}
.product:nth-child(odd) {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

> One alternative to that would be:

```
li:nth-child(2n) {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;   
}
```

Those are just two of the ways, but like I said before - you have many
options to chose from. If you want to see some examples or learn more
about the :nth-child pseudo-class, I suggest checking out the
pseudo-class page on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to apply CSS in a `:nth-child` pseudo-class. Just put all of your styles in there.

```css
.item:nth-child(2n) {
  background: white; /* every other item will have a background white */
}
```